# Looping incorrect in for each loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am pushing na element into a javascript array while it is in for each loop. but the loop is not as expected.

Code:

```
//lets say the length is 1 for array id.If its in error it has to loop 2 times, but looping only once
 $.each(id, function(i, itemI) {
         $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url1.trim(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {//do something
                },
                error: function(xhr,status){
                  //push an element into array here
                  id.push("something");
                }
          });
       })
```

Comment: "asynchronicity"

Comment: What is not expected? You realize that AJAX calls are asynchronous calls and so `id.push` will never happen before the loop is finished?

Comment: @rolfv1 how do i add an element here if it goes to error state?

Comment: even if this worked the way you want, you'd create an infinite loop until the call succeeded - not good for UX!

Comment: @ADyson any suggestions here please?

Comment: Yes - the implication of my previous comment is "don't do it". Find a better and more user-friendly way to handle errors.

Comment: The thing is i have a requirement to make another call with a different id if it goes to error. So i though of implementing like this. But not working..Any better suggestion on implementing this please? @ADyson

Comment: @StackAcc get rid of the loop and make a single request with all the required data

Comment: But sometimes it might go to error state where i need to perfom another ajax call here @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Smells like a design flaw to me. Why might the call fail due to a specific ID? Why might sending a different ID cause it to succeed? Why don't you know what to send the first time?

Comment: @ADyson because if the file is not genrated and not available with that id it will fail in that case. So we have to add another id and get the details.

Comment: You're asking about a problem with what seems like a flawed solution. You may get better answers if you described what you're attempting to achieve as a whole.

Comment: So why don't you know what file IDs are valid beforehand? Again you could just design it so it sends all the IDs that you're looking for, and gets all the details (of the valid ones) at once. Then you only need one call. Unless you can explain a lot more context which justifies it, this doesn't make much sense as a process.

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), `$.each` takes the `length` property of object/array initially and iterate until it meet the `length`.

You can do like this.

```js
var id=0, req = makeReq(id), makecalltimeout;
function makeReq(id)
{
    id = id || "something"; //If id is undefined during first call.
    var data = {id:id};
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "google.com",
        dataType: "json",
        data:data,
        success: function(data) {//do something
        },
        error: function(xhr,status){
           clearTimeout(makecalltimeout);
           makecalltimeout = setTimeout(makeReq(Math.floor(Math.random()*10)),1000)
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here I will make the request when it fails recursively with a time interval of 1 second. Just to send random data in the params, I have used `Math.floor(Math.random()*10`. You can replace with what you like.